# One to Many to One relationship in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationships

I have `company`, `employee` and `motorCycle` table.

One Company has many employee. One employee has One motorCycle

**Company.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Company extends Model
{
    protected $table      = 'company';
    protected $primaryKey = '_id';

    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Employee::class);
    }
}
?>
```

**Employee.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Employee extends Model
{
    protected $table      = 'employee';
    protected $primaryKey = '_id';

    public function motorCycle()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(MotorCycle::class, 'motorCycle', 'id');
    }
}
?>
```

**MotorCycle.php**

```
 <?php

    namespace App\Model;


    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class MotorCycle extends Model
    {
        protected $table      = 'motorCycle';
        protected $primaryKey = 'id';

        public function employee()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('MotorCycle::class');
        }
    }
    ?>
```

I would like to fetch result in controller like below

```
   public function show(Company $company)
    {
        return $company->employee()->offset(0)->limit(20)->motorCycle()->get();

    }
```

I am trying to browse this URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/comapanys/1`

My route is like below

`Route::apiResource('comapanys', 'ComapanyController');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what kind of result do you want to display? you want to have a list of employees and his/her motorcycle in a certain company?

may you can return a query like this.

```
public function show(Company $company)
{
 return $company->employee()->with('motorCycle')->offset(0)->limit(20)->get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kevin. Yes, I want to have a list of employees and his/her motorcycle in a certain company.

Comment: @abuabu no problem dude :)

Answer (score 0):

There is to many problem in your code.
 First, for example you write `class company extends Model` but in controller you use `Company $company`. Also for class employee `class employee extends Model` but in motoCycle class `return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Employee');`. Use naming convention like first letter uppercase for model name .
Second, i`m not sure but I don`t think you can chain eloquent methods like this `return $company->employee()->offset(0)->limit(20)->motorCycle()->get();`. Offset and limit should be on the end of chain.
Also use `(Employee::class)` instead of `('App\Model\Employee')`